# Better way to do this in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have been given the following table from a data set. I have to process the dataset this is the code I have been using thus far:

| X_1 | X_2 |
| --- | --- |
| <chr> | <chr> |
| 16% (4/25) | 32% (8/25) |
| 16% (4/25) | 32% (8/25) |
| 16% (4/25) | 32% (8/25) |
| 16% (4/25) | 32% (8/25) |
| 16% (4/25) | 32% (8/25) |

```
library(tidyverse)
names(age) <- c("Age18.25","Age26.35","Age36.45","Age46.55","Age56.65","Agegt65")
age <- age %>%
  dplyr::select(names(age)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate( Age18.25 = sub('\\%.*', '', Age18.25),
    Age26.35 = sub('\\%.*', '', Age26.35),
    Age36.45 = sub('\\%.*', '', Age36.45),
    Age46.55 = sub('\\%.*', '', Age46.55),
    Age56.65 = sub('\\%.*', '', Age56.65),
    Agegt65 = sub('\\%.*', '', Agegt65))
age[] <- lapply(age, function(x) as.numeric(x))
head(age)
```

Is there a better way to do make this possible to do for the other dataframes that I have to do the same for? All the data frames have the same makeup I just want to extract percentages, however, columns vary and columns name have been giving an issue when I do this way making me rename them.

THis is the output.

| X_1 | X_2 |
| --- | --- |
| <dbl> | <dbl> |
| 16 | 32 |
| 16 | 32 |

Here is the dput head age:

```
structure(list(Age18.25 = c(11, 9, 40, 41, 19, 17), Age26.35 = c(18, 
20, 23, 26, 30, 23), Age36.45 = c(18, 28, 17, 19, 12, 22), Age46.55 = c(14, 
15, 7, 15, 14, 23), Age56.65 = c(14, 8, 13, 0, 14, 13), Agegt65 = c(25, 
20, 0, 0, 12, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The output? You mean?

Comment: No, the best practice on this forum is to share reproducible example input data. One easy way to do this in R is with the `dput` function, which allows us to recreate the content and underlying structure of your data exactly, saving effort and greatly reducing the potential for miscommunication. So `dput(age)` or `dput(head(age))`, and then paste that output into your question.

Comment: @JonSpring I did not know that and I add dput(head(age)) but it was processed already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop `across` all the columns, remove the substring with `str_remove` and convert to numeric

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
age <- age %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(str_remove(., '%.*'))))
```

---

Or another option is `parse_number` from `readr`

```
age %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ readr::parse_number(.)))
```

Comment: So this is column independent right? So I can use this on other dataframes with varying column length.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky It is column independent i.e. for all the columns (`everything()`)

Answer (score 3):

As akrun provided already best answer. I would like to add `sub`
Update: removed escape. Thanks to  Chris Ruehlemann!

```
library(dplyr)
age %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(sub("%.*", "",.))))
```

Output:

```
    X_1   X_2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    16    32
2    16    32
3    16    32
4    16    32
5    16    32
```

Comment: There's no need to escape `%`; it's not a metacharacter

Comment: Thank you Chris Ruehlemann. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner `base R` solution:

```
sapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(sub("%.*", "", x)))
        X1      X2
[1,] 45.00 566.000
[2,] 12.33   0.009
[3,]  1.00  33.000
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  X1 = c("45% (4/25)", "12.33%", "1"),
  X2 = c("566", "0.009% (8/66)", "33%")
)
```